# Clicking url in test environment gives routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a link

`link_to 'Priority visitor', 'http://visitor.othersite.com/vip'`

In development environment, clicking that link goes to the correct place.  However in test environment, there is an get an exception:

```
ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [GET] "/vip"
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you try stopping spring? `spring stop`?

Comment: Is the link pointing to an external site? you shouldn't go to external sites on tests.

Comment: @arieljuod, it is pointing to an external site. I use the vcr gem so that once I have recorded the correct response, I do not keep accessing the external site every time I run the test.

Comment: @SebastianPalma, I have tried ```spring stop```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having stepped through the rspec code, it looks like it is behaving normally because my default test driver is `:rack_test`, which does ignore the host domain and just redirects to path, in this case `'/vip'`.